# R C stack usage 7970720

Tags: r

This is the error we are having issues with:

Error: C stack usage  7970720 is too close to the limit
Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'statistic'.

Of which, our code looks like this:

[Code for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLDrJ.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post the code here directly. Just check any question out here ans an example. Doing so will make it easier for others to help. Also try to provide an reproduce example, even though this is admittedly difficult with memory problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to trace back the problem with the information you provide. My guess is that the problem is something else than a stack size / memory problem you actually see. How big is your dataset? Are your dplyr versions up to date? Which OS are you using? What is your dataset like

There a `C_stack_size` diagnostic functions etc, but I suggest to run code line by line outside of the rmarkdown context in order to debug and post your results here.